# Re-arranging the equation $d=v_i\,t+\frac{a\,t^2}{2}$ to get $t$ equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find $t$ equation by re-arranging the equation 
$\left(d=v_i\,t+\frac{a\,t^2}{2}\right)$
but I'm facing problem because the variable $t$ is existed in two terms.

My try (uncompleted solution):

$$\begin{align}
d=v_i\,\color{#00F}{t}+\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t^2}}{2}\\\\
d-\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t^2}}{2}=v_i\,\color{#00F}{t}\\\\
d-\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t^2}}{2}=v_i\,\color{#00F}{t}\\\\
\color{#00F}{t}=\frac{d}{v_i}-\frac{a\,\color{#F05}{t^2}}{2\,v_i}\\\\
\frac{\color{#00F}{t}}{1}+\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t^2}}{2\,v_i}=\frac{d}{v_i}\\\\
\frac{2\,\color{#00F}{t}\,v_i}{2\,v_i}+\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t^2}}{2\,v_i}=\frac{d}{v_i}\\\\
\color{#00F}{t}\left(1+\frac{a\,\color{#F00}{t}}{2\,v_i}\right)=\frac{d}{v_i}\\\\
\end{align}$$

How can I complete the re-arranging to get $t$ equation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a quadratic equation in $t$, so if you know the quadratic formula you can do this: $$d=v_it+\frac {at^2}2\\\frac a2t^2+v_it-d=0\\t=\frac {-v_i \pm \sqrt{v_i^2+2ad}}a$$  Probably you want the plus sign.

Comment: Thank you very much Ross, but I have a question. When I use the variable $d$ number, should I take $-d$ or $d$ ?

Comment: Are you asking about $d$ or the $\pm sign before the square root?  Usually $d$ starts from zero and increases, so is positive.  The sign in front of it shows what to do, but $d$ is then always positive.  In the second line you would take $d$ positive, but subtract it because of the minus sign.

Answer (score 4):

$$d=v_{i}t+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$$
$$2d=at^{2}+2v_{i}t$$
$$\frac{2d}{a}=t^{2}+\frac{2v_{i}}{a}t$$
$$\frac{2d}{a}=\left(t+\frac{v_{i}}{a}\right)^{2}-\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{a^{2}} $$
(That step is called 'Completing the square')
$$\frac{2d}{a}+\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{a^{2}}=\left(t+\frac{v_{i}}{a}\right)^{2}$$
$$t+\frac{v_{i}}{a}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2d}{a}+\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{a^{2}}}$$
Simplifying the square root, we get
$$\sqrt{\frac{2d}{a}+\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{a^{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2ad+v_{i}^{2}}{a^{2}}}=\frac{\sqrt{2ad+v_{i}^{2}}}{a}$$
So, finally, $$t=\frac{-v_{i}\pm \sqrt{2ad+v_{i}^{2}}}{a}$$
$t$ and $v_{i}$ are usually positive, so you most likely want the positive root.

Alternatively, you could use the [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Derivation_of_the_quadratic_formula) to immediately write this answer down.

Comment: Some physical intuition: it is very natural to look at the term $T=t + \frac{v_i}{a}$. This corresponds to shifting the time to the point when the body had zero velocity. In this reference the equation is $d=\frac{1}{2} aT^2+c$, where $c$ is the position of the body at $T=0$, and this can be easily solved for $T$.